# Javascript onclick function. Input block. Expected block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Question: I'm not getting the desired output. That is the "EXPECTED BLOCK".

INPUT BLOCK:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  Comment 1 -->
<!-- <#if> Comment 2 </#if> -->
```

EXPECTED BLOCK:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  Comment 1 -->
<#if> Comment 2 </#if>
```

Codepen Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLrxvw

1. Open that codepen link.
2. Put the INPUT BLOCK CODE in text area.
3. The EXPECTED BLOCK should be the output.

Only change in output is "UNCOMMENTING" the last comment.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Not getting desired output. Please open this link. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLrxvw Desired output is the "EXPECTED BLOCK"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.map()` , `.indexOf()` , `.outerHTML`

```js
function processString() {
  var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea"); 
  txtArea.value = "";
  var comments = $($("#txtBox").val())
  .map(function(i, el) {
    return (el.outerHTML || el.data).indexOf("<#if>") == -1 
    ? (el.outerHTML 
       || (el.nodeType === 8 ? "<--" + el.data + "-->" : el.textContent))
    : el.data
  }).get();
  txtArea.value = comments.join("")
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" id="txtBox"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  Comment 1 -->
<!-- <#if> Comment 2 </#if> --> </textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Process String" onclick="processString()" style="width:250px" />
<br /><br />
<textarea id="txtArea" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
```